# perl5 code with (ignored) perl6 data types

Tags: raku, perl

I want to start prepping some perl5 code for perl6.  in particular, I like the idea of declaring what types my variables are supposed to be. perl6 defines Bool, Int, Array, Hash, Num, Complex, Pair, and Str.  So I would in essence like to do the equivalent of a C preprocessor `#define Int /**/` for now.  It would be even better if it would check the data type, but I can live without it.

Easy?  Hard?  Impossible?

Answer (score 7):

You would have to write a parser that can parse Perl 5. Unless your code is fairly simple, that's pretty high on the hardness scale.

Also, I found that I structure Perl 6 programs very much different from Perl 5 code. You can technically stay very close to 1:1 one a line by line basis when porting Perl 5 to Perl 6 but the result wont be idiomatic, slow and hard to maintain when you fully switch to Perl 6. Just adding empty macros will not help you much because every mistake you make is just ignored. That may actually increase the burden when you want to port the program for good.

The idea has appeal but you may just increase your workload for no real gain.

Answer (score 5):

There are several Perl 5 modules that go into that direction. For object orientation you can use `Moose` and `MooseX::Method::Signatures`.

For declaring subs and methods there is `Method::Signatures`, `Sub::Signatures` and `Kavorka`.

Also look in the `Perl6`namespace on CPAN.